# using spl_autoload_register to load classes that extends to another class

Tags: php

Well, i got this oop:

```
abstract class TestSystemUtils {

abstract public function __run();
/* utils funcs */

}

class TestSystem extends TestSystemUtils {
protected $body;
protected $out;
function __construct() { }
public function __run() { } 
}
```

I got a directory with many modules, each module is a class that extends TestSystem but i don't want to include all them modules then in method __run i make a dbconnection get these modules that will be used, but in this point idk the right way to 'include' these files i can use __autoload func but idk if i should call these classes inside the class TestSystem or not, all modules need to use these two variables 'body' and 'out' ... Well what's the right way to do it? someone could help me please.

Module classes look like:

```
class mod01 extends TestSystem { }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the most cases, you should use JIT (Just In Time) Loading.
This way you'll be loading and compiling only code that you'll use. The bigger the project the more impact it will have.

It is also advisable to use spl_autoload_register(), since it's more powerful than __autoload(), and it gives you a better way to register an autoloader than a single function laying around.

In summary:
1) Don't include / require code you won't be using in that script run.
2) Encapsulate as much as you can in classes and let the autoloaders include those as they're needed.

Comment: could u give me a example?